# insert date of birth into sql server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I made a JavaScript for date of birth, when debugging you choose your day of birth in three drop down boxes. One for days one for months and one for years. I'm working on C# asp.net. The problem is when i click on test(which is submit or confirm) the date is not taken to the database table. It fills empty! Any help would be appreciated..

here's the code:

DateOfBirth.js:

```
function date_populate(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield) 
{
    var today = new Date();
    var dayfield = document.getElementById(dayfield);
    var monthfield = document.getElementById(monthfield);
    var yearfield = document.getElementById(yearfield);

    for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
    {
        dayfield.options[i] = new Option(i , i + 1)
        dayfield.options[today.getDate()] = new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true)
    }

    for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++) 
    {
         monthfield.options[m] = new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
         monthfield.options[today.getMonth()] = new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true)
    }

    var thisyear = today.getFullYear()
    for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        yearfield.options[y] = new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
        thisyear -= 1
    }

    yearfield.options[0] = new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true)
}
```

Form.asp.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String D, M, Y, Full;

    D = Day.Value.ToString();
    M = Month.Value.ToString();
    Y = Year.Value.ToString();

    Full = D + "/" + M + "/" + Y;
}
```

Comment: At any part of your codes you connect / use / referer to a database. How would it take the date from the database ?

Comment: Can you post the code which calls the database Sp / Query to insert the date into database?

Comment: The code that you have shown seems all right, so the problem is likely in some part of the code that you haven't shown. Have you verified that you get any values from the dropdowns, e.g. `Day.Value`? Does the code that writes to the database use the variable `Full`? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: @SirSaad It's off the track i know but a user can select 31'st Feb as his birthdate are you handling that some way?

Comment: @Ksven it's not selecting from the database it's inserting..

Comment: @SirSaad Are you getting any errors? If not then as Guffa already asked please show us the insert logic.

Comment: @patil.rahulk SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Alumni (DateOfBirth) VALUES "
                    + " (@DateOfBirth)";

Comment: try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1]; 
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
            param[0].Value = dateofbirth;
for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            }
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

Comment: @SurajSingh i'll work on some restriction later dw!

Comment: @SirSaad Are you getting any errors?Have you tried to execute your query in SSMS?Check if you are receiving any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Don't construct dates as strings. Pass them *as dates*. For example:

```
DateTime dob = new DateTime(Year.Value, Month.Value, Day.Value);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", dob);
```

where the `cmd.CommandText` involves `@dob` when you want to refer to the date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

Format the date 'yyyy-mm-dd' and it will insert.

Are you using a stored procedure?

Comment: it is unclear to me how "stored procedure" would change anything here; a correctly parameterized command-text works basically identically

Answer (score 0):

Change your SP parameter from SqlDbType.NVarChar to SqlDbType.DateTime and then pass the date as a DateTime object to the parameter. You dont need to worry about conversions anymore.

```
    DateTime dateofbirth = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yearfield.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(monthfield.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(dayfield.SelectedValue));

    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    param[0].Value = dateofbirth;
```